# Having issue with health bar in the game

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently coding a game but, when i do subtract the health from the player each time it subtracts from full health, but I want it to subtract from the remained health, and I've tried couple of code for the player swap but I can't get it work.

```
import random

health1=health2=100

char1='|' * (health1 / 2)
char2='|' * (health2 / 2)
players=[char1,char2]

char1 = raw_input("Player One: ")
while char1 == "":
    char1 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")


char2 = raw_input("Player two: ")
while char2 == char1:
    char2 = raw_input(char1 + " name is taken, please choose another name: ")
while char2 == "":
    char2 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print char1 + " and " + char2 + " welcome to the game."

toss = random.randint(0, 1)
if toss == 0:
    print char1+" will start the game"
else:
    print char2+" will start the game"

print char1,'|' * (health1 / 2),
print char2,'|' * (health2 / 2)

def magnitude(n):
    if toss==0:
        print char1,'|' * ((health1 /2)-(n))
        magnitude(input(char1 + " select n force: "))
        return
    else:
        print char2,'|' * ((health2 /2)-(n))
        magnitude(input(char2 + " select n force: "))
        return
magnitude(input("select n force: "))
```

Comment: Well i dont see you removing from `health1` or `health2` anywhere... so of course its going to remove from the total health...

Comment: you also never cast `n` to int for `(health1 /2)-(n)`...the problem likely lies in that you don't update `toss` before calling magnitude()

Comment: how can i update, am totally new, give me more a bit more specific answers please, so i can understand and change the codes

Comment: `return` what? `print char1,'|' * ((health1 /2)-(n))` doesn't change anything because it's a print statement (If I had `print 2 - 1` you wouldn't expect `2 == 1` to be `True`) and `return` on its own just returns `None`. You have no global variables being updated here.

Comment: inside `magnitude()` you execute `magnitude()` so you have recursion, and it never ends it so you never leave `magnitude()` - it never reachs lines with `return`

Comment: i deleted the return and again i end up getting the same stuff

Comment: @umerselmani because of the first part of my comment. Printing the value of a subtraction does not inherently change the values themselves. `health1` will always be the same value, you're just visualising the result of subtracting some number from it.

Comment: I'm working on rearranging this code - does it specifically have to be for Python 2.7? This answer can be simplified a bit if you upgraded to Python 3 (since you use both `input` and `raw_input`).

Comment: @roganjosh so if i do return instead of print will the situation change?

Comment: No, changing `return` alone will not fix this. It still wouldn't update `health1`/`health2` globally, but I'm just trying to understand what you thought was going on so I can address that specifically

Comment: @roganjosh if you can code in python 2.7 yeah please :)

Comment: Err, this is turning into a major re-write that goes beyond the scope of the site tbh. To disentangle your various issues whilst keeping the code out of OOP is taking more than I initially thought. Quite substantially. I will work on it for a bit more to keep it in the approach you're using but it also might not be appropriate to post as an answer since it goes far beyond the initial scope of your question. To be useful content, I should keep it focused but that's maybe not possible in order to get a program that works.

Comment: inside function you have to use `global health1` to get access to external variable (without this you can get value from external `health1` but you can't assign new value to external `health1`). And inside function you have to assign new value to variable to keep it `health1 = (health1 / 2) - n`. The same with `health2`.

Comment: @roganjosh: if you wish, you can post a Community Wiki answer _and_ vote to close. It's up to you whether you spend time adjusting the question to make it more on-topic.

Comment: @halfer in this case I guess the posted answer has solved the issue for the OP. I initially thought I could do something useful as a a straightforward answer and it's my fault for suggesting as such (it would be possible to throw `global` around, or fully rewrite to be OOP). I've closed _plenty_ of questions but in this case I think it was misjudgement on my behalf on what was needed and what I could deliver that I think would be useful.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you try to do but I would do it without fuction, only using `while` loop

```
import random

# --- 

char1 = raw_input("Player One: ")

while char1 == "":
    char1 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")

char2 = raw_input("Player two: ")
while char2 == char1:
    char2 = raw_input(char1 + " name is taken, please choose another name: ")
while char2 == "":
    char2 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print char1, "and", char2, "welcome to the game."

# --- 

health1 = 50
health2 = 50

print char1, '|' * health1
print char2, '|' * health2

toss = random.randint(0, 1)

if toss == 0:
    print char1, "will start the game"
else:
    print char2, "will start the game"

# ---

while health1 > 0 and health2 > 0:
    if toss == 0:
        n = input(char1 + " select n force: ")
        health1 -= n
        print char1, '|' * health1
        toos = 1 # change player
    else:
        n = input(char2 + " select n force: ")
        health2 -= n
        print char2, '|' * health2
        toos = 0 # change player

# ---

if health1 > 0:
    print char1, 'wins'
else:
    print char2, 'wins'
```

Or using also lists to keeps chars and healths

```
import random

# ---

char1 = raw_input("Player One: ")

while char1 == "":
    char1 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")

char2 = raw_input("Player two: ")
while char2 == char1:
    char2 = raw_input(char1 + " name is taken, please choose another name: ")
while char2 == "":
    char2 = raw_input("Please enter your name: ")
print char1, "and", char2, "welcome to the game."

chars = [char1, char2]

# ---

healths = [50, 50]

print chars[0], '|' * healths[0]
print chars[1], '|' * healths[1]

toss = random.randint(0, 1)

print chars[toss], "will start the game"

# ---

while healths[0] > 0 and healths[1] > 0:
    n = input(chars[toss] + " select n force: ")
    healths[toss] -= n
    print chars[toss], '|' * healths[toss]
    toss = (toss + 1) % 2 # change player

# ---

if healths[0] > 0:
    print chars[0], 'wins'
else:
    print chars[1], 'wins'
```

Comment: Thank You so much mate, appreciate your code, easy and understandable